# How do I show/hide elements on a page using jquery?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I am trying to hide check-box selectors in the [custom search module](https://drupal.org/project/custom_search) when the page initially loads and then have a clickable link to show them. I have the clickable link working but the check-boxes are initially in a visible state. How can I hide the check boxes when the page/module loads? I tried placing the following code in my THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) function

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { $("#edit-custom-search-types")[0].hide(); });', 'inline');
```

and

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { $("#edit-custom-search-types").hide(); });', 'inline');
```

But neither worked. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For Drupal 7

```
drupal_add_js('(function ($) { $("#edit-custom-search-types").hide(); }(jQuery));', 'inline');
```

[Working with JavaScript and jQuery](https://drupal.org/node/171213)

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks! here is my final code:
`drupal_add_js('(function ($) { $("#edit-custom-search-types").css("visibility","hidden"); }(jQuery));', 'inline');
drupal_add_js('(function ($) 
{
$("#adv_search_link").click(function() 
{
if( $("#edit-custom-search-types").css("visibility") == "hidden" ) 
{
$("#edit-custom-search-types").css("visibility","visible");
} 
else 
{
$("#edit-custom-search-types").css("visibility","hidden");
}});}(jQuery));', 'inline');
`

Comment: Why did this get down votes?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way of adding custom javascript-snippets is to create a custom.js file in your themefolder and declare it in your theme.info file like scripts[] = custom.js. Add all your snippets there.

In your JS file you can hide the elements. 
If you have multiple checkboxes create an array and hide them with a for each loop.

example

```
// create array with stuff you want to hide
    checkboxes = [
        '#checkbox1',
        '#checkbox2',
    ];

// Hide arrays
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        jQuery(checkboxes[i]).hide();
    }
```